# Show indicator while loading images

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a DataTemplate that loads a lot of thumbnails from a server API.

```
 <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lls_PhotoHub" Margin="0,10,0,0" LayoutMode="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Media}" GridCellSize="106,106">
      <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Thumb}" />
           </DataTemplate>
      </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there a way to show an "indiator", that a thumb is still downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is to use the [Codinf4Fun toolkit](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com), it has a control named SuperImage this controls has a placeholder image property.
When you set your loading image to that property, it will be shown while the real image is fetched from the internet.

More detail [here...](http://metronuggets.com/2013/06/11/coding4fun-toolkit-introducing-superimage/)